# List all Alert rules in Azure monitor using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-monitoring

I am trying to list all the Alert rules that I have created in Azure Monitor using the Azure CLI so that I can enable/disable them as per need. Is there a way to achieve this programmatically using the Azure CLI?

Answer (score 1):

Try the command below, more details refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/alert?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-alert-list).

```
az monitor alert list --resource-group
```

Or you can use [`az monitor metrics alert list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/metrics/alert?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-metrics-alert-list) to list metric-based alert rules.

Comment: Hi this comes up as []. I have setup 6 alerts in my subscription which do not show up with the cmdlets

Comment: @AkashMasand Just run `az monitor alert list` , do not specific the resource group.

Comment: Throws an error.
az monitor alert list: error: the following arguments are required: --resource-group/-g
See what I found:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52854105/can-we-view-a-log-analytics-alert-in-azure-using-azure-cli-or-powershell?rq=1

Comment: @AkashMasand Your alert is new or classic?

Comment: Its a new alert in teh Azure Monitor Console

Comment: @AkashMasand For new alert, it was not supported via cli ago, refer to [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51279259/to-create-the-log-analytics-alerts-using-azure-power-shell-or-azure-cli/51280442#51280442) I have answered, but it was in July,  the docs seem to have been updated. Let me check it if possible currently.

Comment: @AkashMasand Seems find that, the `az monitor metrics alert list ` mentioned in my answer is for the new alert, the new alert called `metric alert`, you could try it. I have tried it, seems work fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183336/discussion-between-akash-masand-and-joy-wang).

Comment: By any chance, do anyone knows where one could obtain a list of all possible alerts based on the resource? For example, I know that the alerts for a Data Factory are not the same as the alerts for a Database.